# I am trying to embed a youtube video in my webpage but it does not show at all

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, embed

I am new to HTML programming so please bear with me here. Why is the embedded you tube video not showing? Am I missing something here? i also included the CSS file in case it is necessary I appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Mysteries</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<html>
<body class="index">

<div id="header_box">
    <h4 class="logo">MYSTERIES<span class="orange2">/</span>PARANORMAL</h4>
    <a  href="index2.html" id="content_link">CONTENT</a>
</div>


<div id="footer">
    <h4>&#60;OKLAH/WEBSOFT&#62; 2015 All Rights Reserved.</h4>
<div>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed  /Gas8f7dJfWc?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>


Here is the CSS Code for the webpage, please keep in mind im new  to all this, so i might have some css errors in there

#header_box {
z-index: 1;
position: fixed;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: 1px solid #FFF;
width: 100%;
height: 22px;
left: -2px;
padding: 1em 1.5em;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-right: 1.5em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
padding-left: 1.5em;
top: 0px;

}

.index {
background: #000;
}

.logo {
color: white;
font-family: Verdana;
font-weight: 300px;
float: left;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
font-size: 16px;


}

}
.orange2 {
color: #FF6600;
}
.orange {
color: #FF6600;
}
.h2 {
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
font-family: ISOCT;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
img {
float: center;
width: 55px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 70px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

p {
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
font-family: ISOCT;
font-size: 20px;

}
#paranormal_cont {
color: #FFF;
font-family: Verdana;
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 20px;
}
#paranormal_cont:hover{
border: 1px;
border-style: dotted;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FF6600;
}
#content_link {
color: #FFF;
font-family: Verdana;
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 50px;
}

#content_link:hover {
border: 1px;
border-style: dotted;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FF6600;

}

#footer {

position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: 1px solid #FFF;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
left: -1px;
}

#footer h4 {
position: relative;
text-align: left;
color: #FFF;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 300px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to close the footer-div. This is why you didn't see the iframe.

Also, mentioning it for completeness sake "Change the link so it has no space in it", although you already ruled it out as a problem, since you said

> actually there is no space in the original code, so the link is ok,
>   what else could it be?

For completeness, here you have the whole working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Mysteries</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<html>
<body class="index">

<div id="header_box">
    <h4 class="logo">MYSTERIES<span class="orange2">/</span>PARANORMAL</h4>
    <a  href="index2.html" id="content_link">CONTENT</a>
</div>


<div id="footer">
    <h4>&#60;OKLAH/WEBSOFT&#62; 2015 All Rights Reserved.</h4>
</div> <!-- You forgot to close this div -->

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gas8f7dJfWc?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually there is no space in the original code, so the link is ok, what else could it be?

Comment: I'll update my answer with the complete code which is working. It's not working for you, could you open your console and see if there are any errors in it?

Comment: OK i cheked the console, but its not showing any errors

Comment: Ok, So I've checked your CSS. Give your footer a height of 400px for example and you'll see the video. So there is nothing wrong with the iframe. It's the css.

Comment: i see it now, but ok why in earth is it showing on the footer instead of the body?

Comment: The reason this is happening is because you forgot to close the footer div. I've updated the answer and the code so this should work now without changing the css.

Comment: i have it working now, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @SidneyVogel 

No problem at all :) . I assume you are new here? 

Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask.

Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

See you around :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in the URL for the youtube video. Remove it.

Change this:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed  /Gas8f7dJfWc?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

To this:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gas8f7dJfWc?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

**UPDATE**
You also didn't close your footer .

I've updated the fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanschweitzer/afo1kv5z/1/)

Comment: actually there is no space in the original code, so the link is ok, what else could it be?

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanschweitzer/afo1kv5z/) that shows it working when the space is removed.

Comment: Maybe you have some CSS that's affecting it. You could include your CSS in your question if you think that might be a problem...

Comment: i now included the CSS code, please review it one more time, thank you.

Comment: You didn't have your footer <div> closed, which I didn't notice without the CSS.

Comment: i have it working now, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score -1):

Use this as an example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K9NCz43Ryw4?autoplay=1"   allow= autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"  allowFullScreen> </iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K9NCz43Ryw4?autoplay=1"   allow= autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"  allowFullScreen> </iframe>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).